# Summary for drop-down list

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a problem with drop-down list feature in Excel. 
I need to create a summary for all objects  from the list but I don't know how not to do it manually.

To be more specific: I have a worsheet with customers' data, like turnover or volume. A customer is chosen from a drop-down list and then Excel calculates these values (e.g. total turnover etc.). I need to create a summary with total turnover for each customer so that everything will be clearly visible in a table. The problem is that it is necessary that this summary should automatically refresh. However I don't know any other way how to do it than manually copy the data for each customer. Do you know how to prepare such a summary using a drop-down list?

Regards

Comment: Typically what people do is they'll have the drop-down cell be the lookup value for a `VLOOKUP`, to which all the cells in the summary table would change for.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. However it didn't resolve my problem, because the function looked for one particular item from the drop-down list. As I said the idea is to create a summary for all items from the list. Do you know how to handle it?

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you're looking for or I (or anyone else) won't be able to help you. Undoubtedly, the reason your question has gained no traction is because no one is certain on what you're trying to do. You've mentioned drop-down list of customer names, and drop-down lists of item names. I'd suggest remaking your post and coming back to us with one **clear, specific** question so that we can help you.